# Can't pull repo: Could not resolve hostname: Name or service not known

Tags: git, github

I am trying to pull the latest version of a repo that someone else has cloned to a remote server - I'm not sure exactly what they've done, but now I can't pull, and the repo is behind master.

I've sshed to the server as the `radiator` user. `git remote -v` gives me this:

```
origin  git-radiator:myco/myrepo.git (fetch)
origin  git-radiator:myco/myrepo.git (push)
```

Checking on GitHub, the repo https://github.com/myco/myrepo (substituting the correct values) definitely exists. But when I try to do `git pull origin master` I see this:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname git-radiator: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Meanwhile, running `ssh -T git@github.com` gives me:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Checking the repo on GitHub, I can see there's a read-only deploy key set up, in a different name (`ubuntu@`). However, the repo on the server is a few commits behind master, so clearly it's not being pushed automatically at the moment.

For now, I would just like to clone the repo to the server. What's the easiest way to do this?

I could add a new public key for this user, and copy it to GitHub, which would give me read/write access to the repo. I suspect however that the person who set up this arrangement probably didn't intend for the `radiator` user to have full access to GitHub.

Comment: A Github remote looks like `git@github.com:username/reponame.git`, `git-radiator:myco/myrepo.git` assume you have `git-radiator` in your `/etc/hosts` and have the right config in `ssh-config` to use the rights credentials on this hostname. From what I understand of the situation the remotes are just wrong

Comment: what is the hostname of your server?

Comment: Even if I still think the remotes are wrong, if you want to `ssh -T git@github.com` from the server and hope to be logged as "you" on Github you have to [forward ssh agent](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/)

Answer (score 0):

The setup for you should be the following:

The `origin` should be

```
git@github.com:myco/myrepo.git
```

You should add a deploy key for the user using the account (I think in you case `radiator`).

Then the user `radiator` on your server should be able to clone the repository.